# What is cheaper when deployed on aws Node.js or Java Web Services

Tags: node.js, web-services, amazon-web-services

What costs less money when deployed on Amazon Cloud Node.js or Java Web Services?
Or when it does matter. We take into consideration only one way traffic (to server) for many clients.

Answer (score 4):

They're both going to cost roughly the same in terms of hosting costs. In terms of development costs, however, things might be different:

- Node is just Javascript -- it has a huge ecosystem and lots of new developers are using it -- since it's quite 'hip', it's easier to find people to hop onto new projects.
- Java is old school and has been around forever, there are tons of 'senior' guys you can hire (for good $$).
- Node is quite a bit faster to develop with. If you're building a small application, you might spend much less time developing it with Node than Java.

Comment: In AWS Lambda's are functions only. Java and nodejs (javascript)  are developed with the same speed. 
It depends on what you like which one is faster. javascript you can easy write things but Java will give you much more structure.